# Get types of arguments in python

Tags: python, types, arguments

I'm learning python. I like to use help() or interinspect.getargspec to get information of functions in shell. But is there anyway I can get the argument/return type of function.

Comment: What's wrong with the `help` text?  What's wrong with reading the code itself?

Comment: Of course it's wrong. Do you really like reading source code when you just want to call a method.

Comment: this article is telling about the Python 3 with the types of parameters in Python 3.x
https://medium.com/@waqarnaeem2/parameters-in-python-1da9af59cbba

Answer (score 10):

`formatargspec` is deprecated since version 3.5. Prefer `signature`

```py
>>> from inspect import signature
>>> def foo(a, *, b:int, **kwargs):
...     pass

>>> sig = signature(foo)

>>> str(sig)
'(a, *, b:int, **kwargs)'
```

**Note**: Some callables may not be introspectable in certain implementations of Python. For example, in CPython, some built-in functions defined in C provide no metadata about their arguments.

Comment: Is there a way to get built-in types? Where do IDEs get built-in type infos from? I already suspect it's from `.pyi` files, and those are likely included with CPython, so how do I access them, ex. from an `ipython` shell?

Comment: All builtins variables can be listed from builtins module: `import builtins; builtins.__dict__`

Answer (score 9):

In the 3.4.2 documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html, there is a mention of what you exactly need (namely getting the types of arguments to a function).

You will first need to define your function like this:

```
def f(a: int, b: float, c: dict, d: list, <and so on depending on number of parameters and their types>):
```

Then you can use `formatargspec(*getfullargspec(f))` which returns a nice hash like this:

```
(a: int, b: float)
```

Comment: This question is from 2010...well before 3.4.2 existed. I'd consider removing this answer.

Comment: deprecated, use signature instead, see below.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean during a certain call of the function, the function itself can get the types of its arguments by calling `type` on each of them (and will certainly know the type it returns).

If you mean from outside the function, no: the function can be called with arguments of any types -- some such calls will produce errors, but there's no way to know a priori which ones they will be.

Parameters can be optionally decorated in Python 3, and one possible use of such decoration is to express something about the parameters' types (and/or other constraints on them), but the language and standard library offer no guidance on how such decoration might be used.  You might as well adopt a standard whereby such constraints are expressed in a structured way in the function's docstring, which would have the advantage of being applicable to any version of Python.

Answer (score 1):

Best, shortest answer:

Use the **inspect** library with **getfullargspec(function).annotations**
Note that you have to explicitly typecast the function arguments.

```
import inspect

def my_func(arg_1:str="One", arg_2:bool=False):
    pass

spec = inspect.getfullargspec(my_func).annotations

print(spec)

>>> {'arg_1': <class 'str'>, 'arg_2': <class 'bool'>}
```

From this you can use `spec.values()` to get the datatypes of each argument.

Answer (score -2):

There is a function called `type()`.
[Here are the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type)

You can't tell in advance what type a function will return

```
>>> import random
>>> def f():
...  c=random.choice("IFSN")
...  if c=="I":
...   return 1
...  elif c=="F":
...   return 1.0
...  elif c=="S":
...   return '1'
...  return None
... 
>>> type(f())
<type 'float'>
>>> type(f())
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> type(f())
<type 'float'>
>>> type(f())
<type 'int'>
>>> type(f())
<type 'str'>
>>> type(f())
<type 'float'>
>>> type(f())
<type 'float'>
>>> type(f())
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> type(f())
<type 'str'>
```

It is usually good practise to only return one type of object from a function, but Python does not force that upon you